# How to discern what LabVIEW is doing

Tags: labview

I have a snippet of LabVIEW code. The issue is that I am working on a grander project, and therefore have discarded the use of LabVIEW for this project. Would there be a way of how I can decipher what this program in LabVIEW is doing without having to learn all of LabVIEW? I just need to know the final voltage being applied and current. I have worked out that the program is outputting a pulse sequence that has 20 Hz and a 200 microsecond pulse duration. Would there be a way I can simulate this type of program on LabVIEW, instead of learning what each component does?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What would help - exactly VI, or code snippet from LabVIEW (not code screenshot). Then it would be possible to run the code, and save generated signal array to file. As per now, please, check functions below, and there are the links to their description:
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/lvanls/signal_generator_duration/
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/lvanls/ramp_pattern/
[image]

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for the help!